# How to limit function calls across multiple requests in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, concurrency

I am running a backend server with NodeJS. The backend holds a function that makes requests to an external API. As the external API provider isn't too happy about constant requests, I need to throttle my function that makes the requests to this external API. My current solution is to use the [Bottleneck](https://github.com/SGrondin/bottleneck) library.

With that library I can define a limit on how often a specific function is called in a certain amount of time (also I can limit the number of concurrent instances that execute a specific function). There is only one downside: I can neither access nor change the queue of "waiting" function calls, meaning that one client can basically make a lot of requests and block the function for other clients.

Is there a way to sort of implement a queue in NodeJS for function calls? If other clients make requests aswell, I need to take that into account and somehow mix up the execution order to be fair again (and not first in first out/first come first serve).

This is my current setup with Bottleneck, but as described above, the behaviour is FIFO and therefore other clients are getting "blocked".

```
const Bottleneck = require("bottleneck");

const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  minTime: 1000,
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  ...
  const result = await requestHandler(xml, 0);
  async function requestHandler(xml, recursionCounter) {
    ...
    result = await limiter.schedule(() => soapRequest(URL, xml));
    ...
  }
}

async function soapRequest(url, xml) {...}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the job [`priority` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck#job-options) Bottleneck offers suit your needs? When a user submits multiple jobs, increase their priority level by the number of jobs they currently have in the queue (up until 9)?

Comment: Well, only kind of. There will be cases where clients will make hundreds if not thousands of requests - and with that kind of amount 10 different priority levels are simply not enough to split the load to prevent a client from blocking the function for too long.